Python threading lock with cooldown period for rate-limiting
I am using Python 3.12 or newer. I need a threading lock, blocking only, with a cooldown feature that serves as a simple rate limiter. This will help me to avoid hammering a resource excessively.
Expected features:

It must have the typical mutual exclusion feature of a threading lock.
It must not be possible to reacquire it in the 1 second following its last release. This is the cooldown period which is set at initialization.

The correspondingly expected interface is:
def __init__(self, cooldown: float = 1)

def acquire(self)  # Note: For simplicity, there is no 'blocking' or 'timeout' arg.

# As with `threading.Lock`:
def release(self)  # Must not block!
def __enter__(self)
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):

I have a current solution which is posted below as an answer, but I feel that it is not 100% thread safe due to a potential race condition, although it is close to it.
Third-party packages are also acceptable if they have an accurate implementation.

I think this class can be implemented with only a single Lock instance and without any race conditions as follows. The idea is to acquire the lock at the earliest possible time (i.e. immediately if it is not currently held or immediately after it is released by another thread) and if it has been acquired to early, then sleep the necessary amount of time before returning to the acquirer:
import threading
import time
from typing import Optional, Self


class CooldownLock:
    """A lock mechanism that also enforces a cooldown period between releases and subsequent acquisitions.

    This is useful in scenarios where it's also necessary to limit the frequency of lock acquisition,
    such as for managing access to a shared resource in a way that prevents excessively rapid consecutive uses.

    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78591650/
    """

    def __init__(self, cooldown: float = 1, name: Optional[str] = None):
        """Initialize with a specified cooldown period.

        Args:
            cooldown: The cooldown period in seconds after releasing the lock before it can be acquired again.
            name: Optional name of lock used in log messages.
        """
        self._cooldown_period = cooldown
        self._name = f"{name} lock" if name else "lock"

        self._earliest_use_time = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def acquire(self) -> bool:
        # Acquire the lock:
        self._lock.acquire()
        # Did we acquire it too early?
        wait_time = self._earliest_use_time - time.monotonic()
        if wait_time > 0:
            # Yes, we acquired it too early; we just have to wait until the
            # cooldown period has expired:
            print(f"Sleeping for {wait_time:.1f}s to acquire {self._name}.")
            time.sleep(wait_time)
        return True

    def release(self):
        if not self.locked():
            raise RuntimeError('lock not held')
        self._earliest_use_time = time.monotonic() + self._cooldown_period
        self._lock.release()

    def locked(self) -> bool:
        return self._lock.locked()

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        self.acquire()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    from threading import Thread

    def random_wait_1() -> None:
        """Wait for a random amount between 2 and 4 seconds."""
        wait_time = random.random() * 2.0 + 2.0
        time.sleep(wait_time)

    def random_wait_2() -> None:
        """Wait for a random amount between .25 and .75 seconds."""
        wait_time = random.random() / 2.0 + .25
        time.sleep(wait_time)

    def current_time() -> float:
        """Return current time relative to start of program (more or less)"""
        return time.monotonic() - start_time

    def worker(id, lock):
        for _ in range(3):
            # Wait for 2 to 4 seconds to acquire:
            random_wait_1()
            print(f'Thread {id} attempting to acquire lock at time = {current_time()}')
            with lock:
                print(f'Thread {id} acquired lock at time = {current_time()}')
                # Wait for .25 to .75 seconds to release:
                random_wait_2()
            print(f'Thread {id} released lock at time = {current_time()}')


    lock = CooldownLock(1.0)
    threads = [
        Thread(target=worker, args=(id, lock)) for id in range(1, 3)
    ]
    # Set start ot program time:
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

Prints:
Thread 2 attempting to acquire lock at time = 2.984999999869615
Thread 2 acquired lock at time = 2.984999999869615
Thread 2 released lock at time = 3.3129999998491257
Thread 1 attempting to acquire lock at time = 3.8129999998491257
Sleeping for 0.5s to acquire lock.
Thread 1 acquired lock at time = 4.312999999849126
Thread 1 released lock at time = 4.765999999828637
Thread 2 attempting to acquire lock at time = 6.109999999869615
Thread 2 acquired lock at time = 6.109999999869615
Thread 2 released lock at time = 6.578999999910593
Thread 1 attempting to acquire lock at time = 7.734999999869615
Thread 1 acquired lock at time = 7.734999999869615
Thread 1 released lock at time = 8.390999999828637
Thread 2 attempting to acquire lock at time = 8.734999999869615
Sleeping for 0.7s to acquire lock.
Thread 2 acquired lock at time = 9.390999999828637
Thread 2 released lock at time = 9.875
Thread 1 attempting to acquire lock at time = 11.5
Thread 1 acquired lock at time = 11.5
Thread 1 released lock at time = 12.109999999869615


I think release can safely and correctly be simplified to if self.locked(): self._earliest_use_time = time.monotonic() + self._cooldown_period, followed by self._lock.release().

@Asclepius Yes, that is true if you do not care about raising an exception on a call to release when the lock is not already held. But if you tried relasing a threading.Lock instance that is not locked, you would definitely get a RuntimeError exception. But we agree that you definitely do not want to modify self._earliest_use_time if the lock is not actually being released.

This approach tracks the allowable earliest reacquisiton time of the lock.
This answer is here only for historical reasons. It is more complicated than necessary, and probably not 100% race-free. Use a different answer instead, such as this one.
import threading
import time
from typing import Optional, Self


class CooldownLock:
    """A lock mechanism that also enforces a cooldown period between releases and subsequent acquisitions.

    This is useful in scenarios where it's also necessary to limit the frequency of lock acquisition,
    such as for managing access to a shared resource in a way that prevents excessively rapid consecutive uses.

    Caution: The implementation may have a slight race condition, although efforts have been made while acquiring the lock to minimize its impact.

    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78572164/
    """

    def __init__(self, cooldown: float = 1, name: Optional[str] = None):
        """Initialize with a specified cooldown period.

        Args:
            cooldown: The cooldown period in seconds after releasing the lock before it can be acquired again.
            name: Optional name of lock used in log messages.
        """
        self._cooldown_period = cooldown
        self._name = f"{name} lock" if name else "lock"

        self._earliest_use_time = 0
        self._main_lock = threading.Lock()
        self._cooldown_lock = threading.Lock()

    def acquire(self) -> bool:
        num_approvals = 0
        with self._cooldown_lock:
            while num_approvals < 2:  # Intended to minimize effect of race condition.
                wait_time = self._earliest_use_time - time.monotonic()
                if wait_time > 0:
                    print(f"Sleeping for {wait_time:.1f}s to acquire {self._name}.")
                    time.sleep(wait_time)
                    num_approvals = 0
                else:
                    num_approvals += 1
            self._main_lock.acquire()
            return True

    def release(self):
        if self.locked():
            self._earliest_use_time = time.monotonic() + self._cooldown_period
        self._main_lock.release()

    def locked(self) -> bool:
        return self._main_lock.locked()

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        self.acquire()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.release()

